# Show only a part of string in a TextView

Tags: android

I am trying to accomplish a currency converter app for android and I'm using Google Currency Converter to do it by sending an URL with this form :

```
http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q="amount""from currency code"=?"to currency code"
```

Example :-

```
http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=10USD=?EGP
```

and the out put for the Example will be :

```
{lhs: "10 U.S. dollars",rhs: "59.701849 Egyptian pounds",error: "",icc: true}
```

and what I want to do is to show in the TextView (which will show the final result for the user) only this :-

```
59.701849 Egyptian pounds
```

so any ideas will be helpful and thanks for your help in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a JSON string. Use the `JSONObject` class http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(outputString);
String rhs = obj.getString("rhs");
```

Comment: thanks it works fine but when the "rhs" contain a number from 1000 and  larger it display it in this form

Comment: thanks it works fine but when the "rhs" contain a number from 1000 and  larger it display it in this form `rhs: "5 970.1849 Egyptian pounds"` but in the output TextView it look like this pic (http://img403.imageshack.us/img403/6287/outputo.png)

Comment: It could be a non-breaking space maybe? Not sure if you can just html-decode it.